# Set Images in UIImageView from project properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uitableview

I am developing one app that use local database.I am getting id of image and then i am load images in **UITableView** using this.

```
[UIImage imageNamed:imageid];
```

The problem is what when i am populate tableview with 60 or 70 entrys the tableview scrolling is very slow.I have a more then 90 images in project folder. I want to know which is best way for fetch images faster from project properties.Please help.

Comment: first load 10 images, then when you scroll, then load next 10 and so on. This is just an suggestion.

Comment: Try this for once..http://iosdevelopertutorial.blogspot.in/2015/10/how-to-implement-lazy-loading-in-ios-sdk.html

Comment: what code u write in -cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: Are you dequeuing the cell correctly? See template code when creating blank UITableViewController. Also are your images optimised ie not huge in file size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all when you set image from local, then it should be set very quickly. But as you said that it take time then it may be because of your image size. Your image may be very heavy in the size. You can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)  to load image in synchronize mode. and make you app smoother.  you can use local File URL to set image

```
 #import "UIImageView+UIActivityIndicatorForSDWebImage.h"
```

When you want to set image use the below code.

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strURL];
 [cell.imgCategoryIcon setImageWithURL:url usingActivityIndicatorStyle:0];
```

you have different option like `placeholder` image `activityIndicator` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
func getDataFromUrl(url:String, completion: ((data: NSData?) -> Void)) {
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: url)!) { (data, response, error) in
        completion(data: NSData(data: data))
        }.resume()
}

func loadExternalImage(url:String,img:UIImageView){
    getDataFromUrl(url) { data in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
            // do some task
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                img.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            });
        });
    }
}
```

And this how you call:

```
self.loadExternalImage(<UIImage String>, img:<UIImageView Object>)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it easily with SDWebImage as it keep images in cache memory. Insert files of SDWebImage and use this only

```
UIImageView *imgView= [[UIImageView alloc]init];
imgView.frame = CGRectMake(7, 52, 50, 50);
imgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"steert_food"];
[cell.contentView addSubview: imgView];
```

[imgView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_thumbnailUrl] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error,      SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {    }];